# Can Eclipse run a command after build is finished?

Tags: eclipse, notifications, hook, eclipse-cdt

I have a nice notification tool – it displays text under prompt of all active shells (Zsh):

https://asciinema.org/a/156726

I want to notify "Build finished", ideally with additional information "... with 0 warnings 0 errors", maybe also with project name. Is this possible with Eclipse? It just needs to run "zc-bg-notify -q 'text'" after finishing build.

PS. It's CDT, external builder (makefiles in Debug/), gcc toolchain, for STM32 microcontrollers.

Comment: You should be able to do this either through a Maven or an Ant build which can be run from Eclipse.

Comment: What kind of build? Project builder, Maven, Gradle, Ant, ...?

Comment: @howlger: External builder for STM32 microcontroller, AFAIK makefile based (saw makefiles in Debug/), using GCC toolchain. It's the SW4STM32 IDE for STM.

Comment: Since Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0) you can use a [Launch Group](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#launch-groups) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w&t=20s)) for that. Alternatively, it should also be possible to execute two commands one after the other in an external builder. But this depends on the operating system used.